# Best ways to display dynamically changing list items in android

Tags: android, listview, textview

I am new to coding and android and this is my first post...

I am making an android app and am trying to display a list of values that changes dynamically when a user picks from a menu. Originally I just displayed TextViews but wanted a cleaner approach. I have tried using ListView but don't know how to change the list items' text dynamically.

Here is the current approach:

```
public class WeaponTypeListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
private TextView currentWeaponDPS;
private TextView currentWeaponDamage;
private TextView currentWeaponFireRate;
private TextView currentWeaponMagazineSize;
private TextView currentWeaponReloadTime;
private TextView currentWeaponRarity;
private TextView currentWeaponBulletType;

public WeaponTypeListener(TextView currentWeaponDPS,
                          TextView currentWeaponDamage,
                          TextView currentWeaponFireRate,
                          TextView currentWeaponMagazineSize,
                          TextView currentWeaponReloadTime,
                          TextView currentWeaponRarity,
                          TextView currentWeaponBulletType
                          ){
    this.currentWeaponDPS = currentWeaponDPS;
    this.currentWeaponDamage = currentWeaponDamage;
    this.currentWeaponFireRate = currentWeaponFireRate;
    this.currentWeaponMagazineSize = currentWeaponMagazineSize;
    this.currentWeaponReloadTime = currentWeaponReloadTime;
    this.currentWeaponRarity = currentWeaponRarity;
    this.currentWeaponBulletType = currentWeaponBulletType;
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    String selection = Weapons.ALL_WEAPON_TYPES.get(i);
    Weapon stats = Weapons.getWeaponStats(selection);
    this.setWeaponStats(stats);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
}

private void setWeaponStats (Weapon w) {
    this.currentWeaponDPS.setText(Double.toString(w.getDps()));
    this.currentWeaponDamage.setText(Integer.toString(w.getDamage()));
    this.currentWeaponFireRate.setText(Double.toString(w.getFireRate()));
  this.currentWeaponMagazineSize.setText(Integer.toString(w.getMagazineSize()));
    this.currentWeaponReloadTime.setText(Double.toString(w.getReloadTime()));
    this.currentWeaponRarity.setText(w.getRarity());
    this.currentWeaponBulletType.setText(w.getBulletType());
     } 
 }
```

And also:

```
public class WeaponComparisonActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@BindView(R.id.weaponTypeA) Spinner weaponTypeA;
@BindView(R.id.weaponTypeB) Spinner weaponTypeB;
@BindView(R.id.weaponSelectionA) TextView weaponSelectionA;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponDPS) TextView currentWeaponDPS;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponDamage) TextView currentWeaponDamage;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponFireRate) TextView currentWeaponFireRate;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponMagazineSize) TextView currentWeaponMagazineSize;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponReloadTime) TextView currentWeaponReloadTime;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponRarity) TextView currentWeaponRarity;
@BindView(R.id.currentWeaponBulletType) TextView currentWeaponBulletType;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponDPS) TextView potentialWeaponDPS;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponDamage) TextView potentialWeaponDamage;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponFireRate) TextView potentialWeaponFireRate;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponMagazineSize) TextView potentialWeaponMagazineSize;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponReloadTime) TextView potentialWeaponReloadTime;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponRarity) TextView potentialWeaponRarity;
@BindView(R.id.potentialWeaponBulletType) TextView potentialWeaponBulletType;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.weapon_comparison_activity);

    ButterKnife.bind(this);

    ArrayAdapter<String> weaponTypeAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(WeaponComparisonActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, Weapons.ALL_WEAPON_TYPES);
    weaponTypeA.setAdapter(weaponTypeAdapter);
    weaponTypeB.setAdapter(weaponTypeAdapter);


    weaponTypeA.setOnItemSelectedListener(new WeaponTypeListener(
            currentWeaponDPS,
            currentWeaponDamage,
            currentWeaponFireRate,
            currentWeaponMagazineSize,
            currentWeaponReloadTime,
            currentWeaponRarity,
            currentWeaponBulletType)
            );

    weaponTypeB.setOnItemSelectedListener(new WeaponTypeListener(
                    potentialWeaponDPS,
                    potentialWeaponDamage,
                    potentialWeaponFireRate,
                    potentialWeaponMagazineSize,
                    potentialWeaponReloadTime,
                    potentialWeaponRarity,
                    potentialWeaponBulletType)
    );
}
```

Comment: first clear the concepts of listView.
You don't need to inflate multiple textView in adapter.
One's you have cleared the concepts of listView.
There wii be a method to notify on change in the listView
'notifyDatasetChanged' will be the method you will need to call.

Answer (score 1):

Just make a custom adapter for the listview.You can follow this [link](https://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial).

After that, you can simply change the data by calling notifyDataSetChanged() on the adapter.